# How to mock modules in storybook's stories?

Tags: vue.js, mocking, storybook

I have a Vue component which includes some external modules with complicated logic. For example:

```js
// Component.vue
import Vue from 'vue';
import { externalModule } from '@/path/to/module';

export default {
  methods: {
    useExternalModule() {
      externalModule.doSomethig();
    }
  }
};
```

Is it possible to mock the `externalModule` inside the story?

I'm using Storybook v6.

Answer (score 20):

You can create a `__mocks__` folder to put your mock components in. Then in your `.storybook/main.js` file use this to point webpack to your mock file.

```js
module.exports = {
  // your Storybook configuration

  webpackFinal: (config) => {
    config.resolve.alias['externalModule'] = require.resolve('../__mocks__/externalModule.js');
    return config;
  },
};
```

This is covered in the docs under ["Mocking imports"](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/build-pages-with-storybook#mocking-imports).

However, this is a global configuration and not a story level configuration.

Comment: To automatically mock all node_modules that have a manual mock (meaning there is a directory in root `__mocks__` matching it), I overridden the `config.resolve.modules` property:

`config.resolve.modules = [path.resolve(__dirname, "../__mocks__"), ...config.resolve.modules]`